# A linear-time algorithm to find any vertex of a polygon visible from other vertex

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

Suppose there is a polygon with no holes and self-intersections (i.e. a simple polygon) defined by `n` vertices. Choose a reflex vertex `v` of this polygon.

I'd like to find any other vertex `u` of the same polygon which is "visible" from the vertex `v`. By visible I mean, that a line segment between `v` and `u` lies completely inside the polygon.

Is there an algorithm to do that in `O(N)` time or better? Is there an algorithm that can find all visible vertices in `O(N)` time?

A quick research suggests that for a given polygon and any point inside this polygon a [visibility polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_polygon) can be constructed in `O(N)`. I assume that finding a single visible vertex should be even easier.

Comment: Well, there's the [binary space partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning).  It allows visibility checks in O(N), but has a much more complicated setup, so it'd only be good for you if you're checking the same polygon repeatedly, and I'm guessing you're not...

Comment: @XavierHolt: Actually I will do that search multiple times for different vertices V, so a setup that is at most O(N*log N) is OK. But a check in O(N) is probably not sufficient. I could do O(N) check without any data structure just by iterating through all edges of the polygon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem was solved 30 years ago:

> ElGindy and Avis, "A linear algorithm for computing the visibility polygon from a point", *J. Algorithms* **2**, 1981, p. 186--197.

There is a very nice paper by Joe & Simpson, 1985, "Visibility of a simple polygon from a point," that offers carefully verified pseudocode: 
([PDF download link](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1985/CS-85-38.pdf)).
This surely has been implemented many times since, in many languages.
For example, there is a link at [the Wikipedia article on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_polygon).

Comment: In case someone is interested in an implementation of Joe and Simpson's algorithm see [this](https://github.com/davidglavas/Visibility-Polygons-by-Joe-Simpson).

Answer (score 2):

I've modified the algorithm as it was incorrect. I hope this time it covers all cases!.

Start from a reflex *a*, let *a'* the next vertex and follow the polygon until you find an edge that crosses *a--a'* in the side *a'*, let *b* the point of intersection of this edge with the line *a--a'* and *c* the end point of the edge (the one to the right of *a--c*).

Now continue going through the edges of the polygon, and if an edge crosses the segment *a--b* from left to right then set *b* to the new point of intersection and *c* to the end vertex. When you finish we have a triangle *a--b--c*. Now starting again from *c* look every vertex to see if it is inside the triangle *a--b--c* and in that case set *c* to the new vertex. At the end *a--c* is a diagonal of the polygon.

Here is an implementation in C that assumes that the reflex point *a* is in `P[0]`:

```
struct pt {
    double x,y;
    friend pt operator+(pt a, pt b){a.x+=b.x; a.y+=b.y; return a;}
    friend pt operator-(pt a, pt b){a.x-=b.x; a.y-=b.y; return a;}
    friend pt operator*(pt a, double k){a.x*=k; a.y*=k; return a;}
    bool leftof(pt a, pt b) const{
        // returns true if the *this point is left of the segment a--b.
        return (b.x-a.x)*(y-a.y) - (x-a.x)*(b.y-a.y) > 0;
    }
};
pt intersect(pt a, pt b, pt c, pt d){// (see O'rourke p.222)
    double s,t, denom;
    denom = (a.x-b.x)*(d.y-c.y)+ (d.x-c.x)*(b.y-a.y);
    s = ( a.x*(d.y-c.y)+c.x*(a.y-d.y)+d.x*(c.y-a.y) )/denom;
    return a + (b-a)*s;
}
/**
    P is a polygon, P[0] is a reflex (the inside angle at P[0] is > pi).
    finds a vertex t such that P[0]--P[t] is a diagonal of the polygon.
**/
int diagonal( vector<pt> P ){
    pt a = P[0], b = P[1]; //alias
    int j=2;
    if( !b.leftof(a,P[j]) ){
        // find first edge cutting a--b to the right of b
        for(int k = j+1; k+1 < int(P.size()); ++k)
            if( P[k].leftof(a,b) && P[k+1].leftof(b,a) && b.leftof(P[k+1],P[k]) )
                j = k,
                b = intersect( a,b,P[k],P[k+1] );
        // find nearest edge cutting the segment a--b 
        for(int k = j+1; k+1 < int(P.size()); ++k)
            if( P[k].leftof(a,b) && P[k+1].leftof(b,a) &&
                a.leftof(P[k+1],P[k]) && b.leftof(P[k],P[k+1]) ){
                b = intersect( a,b,P[k],P[k+1] );
                j = k+1;
            }
    }
    for(int k = j+1; k+1 < int(P.size()); ++k)
        if( P[k].leftof(a,b) && P[k].leftof(b,P[j]) && P[k].leftof(P[j],a) )
            j = k;
    return j;
}
```

Comment: This seems to almost work. But there is a problem when the polygon is winded too much (spiral polygon), the first found vertex _c_ would not be found correctly. Also the check if a _d_ is inside a triangle may be insufficient, because it may block the visibility of _c_ even if it is not in the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

You can test any individual vertex in **O(n)** time, and hence test all vertices in **O(n^2)**. To test any if any individual vertex **U** is visible from **V**, construct the line between **V** and **U**. Let us call this line **L**. Now, test **L** to see if it intersects any of the polygon edges. If it does not, **U** is *not* obscured from **V**. If it does, **U** *is* obscured.

Further, you can test if **L** lies within the polygon like so: Assume the incident edges on **V** are **E1** and **E2**. Calculate the signed angles between **E1** and **E2** (call this **a1**) and between **E1** and **L** (call this **a2**). The sign of **a2** should be the same as **a1** (i.e., **L** is on the 'same' side of **E1** as **E2** is), and **a2** should be smaller than **a1** (i.e., **L** 'comes before' **E2**).

Be careful with your intersection tests, as **L** will trivially intersect the polygon edges incident to **V**. You can ignore these intersections.

Also, if **U** shares any of the edges incident to **V**, **U** is trivially visible from **V**.

Comment: Which U should I choose? Your algorithm is O(N^2).

Comment: Surely, you also need to check that L lies _inside_ the polygon

Comment: And you should choose the first U that passes the test.

Comment: OK, but after edit it is still O(N^2). I am only interested in O(N) algorithm.

Comment: Fair enough! If I think of something I will let you know. Is it possible for you to pre-process the polygon in any way? Also, out of interest, how many vertices do these polygons have?

Comment: Yes I can preprocess it, but I can spend at most O(N log(N)) time on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a triangulation of the polygon.

Assuming you have a triangulation `T`, a set of visible vertices `U` for a vertex `V` could be found by examining associated internal edges in the triangulation. Specifically, if the set of triangles attached to `V` are traversed and the internal edges identified (those that appear twice!), the set `U` is all edge vertices except `V`.

Note that this is not necessarily *all* visible vertices from `V`, just a set with `|U| >= 0` <s>(must be at least one internal edge from V)</s>. It is efficient though - only `O(m)` where `m` is the number of triangles/edges visited, which is essentially `O(1)` for reasonable inputs.

Of course, you would need to build a triangulation first. There are efficient algorithms that allow a constrained Delaunay triangulation to be built in `O(n*log(n))`, but that's not quite `O(n)`. Good constrained Delaunay implementations can be found in [Triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) and [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/).

Comment: Thanks. A valid answer, but I would rather not implement it this way. Implementation of algorithm for triangulation in O(N*log(N)) is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep going in some direction through vertices starting with V and update list of visible vertices. If I didn't miss anything, that will be O(n).

For simplicity let's call V visible.

I've tried for a day to put it in words, failed and used pseudo-code :)

```
visible_vertices = {V}
for each next segment in counter-clockwise polygon traversal
  if segment is counter-clockwise (looking from V)
    if (visible_vertices.last -> segment.end) is counter-clockwise
      visible_vertices.add(segment.end)
  else
    while segment hides visible_vertices.last or segment.start=visible_vertices.last
      visible_vertices.remove_last
```